# Find string in list by index of found string

Tags: c#, string, list, indexing

If I found string index for equal string exist in list:

```
int index = myList.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(inputStr));
```

what is a proper and fast way to get near strings +1 -1 and replace it for some value:

So desired result, if my list content is:

```
0. hello world 1
1. hello world 2
2. hello world 3
3. hello world 4
```

and input string is equal to "hello world 2" I want found by +1 -1 index by index +1 "hello world 3" or by -1 "hello world 1" and replace it with "X" or just get string as variable to other use.

```
0. hello world 1
1. hello world 2
2. X
3. hello world 4
```

Comment: Note that `line => line == input` means you search for a line that is equal to `input`, and with `x => x.StartsWith(inputStr)` you only check if the line starts with the `input` string.

Comment: And what is the difficulty that you are facing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you can just directly access them like this:

```
int index = myList.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(inputStr));

string previous = myList[index - 1];
string next = myList[index + 1];

// you can change them like this

myList[index - 1] = "x";
myList[index + 1] = "x";
```